Number of cusps of $X_0(p^2)$ for prime $p$

Find the number of cusps on $X_0(p^2)$ (for prime $p$) by finding a complete set of coset representatives for $\Gamma_0(p^2)$ as a subgroup of $\Gamma_0(p)$. Hint: $X_0(p)$ has two cusps, the equivalence classes of $0$ and $\infty$.

My attempt: a complete set of coset representatives is given by\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\ip&1\end{pmatrix} where $0\le i\le p-1$. It is easy to check this is a valid set of representatives. I don't understand how we can use this to count the number of cusps though. The solution given by my instructor is as follows:
Denoting by $A_i$ the above matrix, applying each of the $A_i$ to $0$ and $\infty$ we see that the cusps of $\Gamma_0(p^2)$ are the distinct classes amongst $[0]$ and $[1/pi]$ for $0\le i\le p-1$. We now need to show these are all distinct. Firstly, $0$ is not $\Gamma_0(p^2)$-equivalent to $1/pi$ for any $i$ since it is not $\Gamma_0(p)$-equivalent. Next, suppose $1/pi$ is $\Gamma_0(p^2)$-equivalent to $1/pj$; then for some integers $a,b,c,d,\lambda$ we have $\begin{pmatrix}1\\pi\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\pi^2c&d\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}\lambda\\\lambda i\end{pmatrix}$. From this, with some work, one can deduce that $j\equiv\pm 1\pmod p$ which is what we needed to show.
I don't understand this solution at all; how did they deduce from the set of coset representatives what the form of the cusps must be? And what exactly is the strategy behind the solution? I want to be able to understand everything that's going on here so I can solve similar problems in future!

Recall that the cusps of $X_0(p^2)$ are equivalence classes of $\mathbb{P}^1 (\mathbb{Q})$ under the action of $\Gamma_0(p^2)$ given by
$ \begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{pmatrix} [x:y] = [ax+by: cx+dy]$.
The first thing you might try if you want to compute the cusps of an arbitrary subgroup $\Gamma \subset \operatorname{SL}_2 (\mathbb{Z})$ is to note that $\operatorname{SL}_2 (\mathbb{Z})$ acts transitively on $\mathbb{P}^1(\mathbb Q)$, so there is a unique orbit. That is, we can write $\mathbb{P}^1 (\mathbb{Q}) = \operatorname{SL}_2(\mathbb{Z}) \cdot \{\infty\}$, say. Now, if we can find a set of elements, or coset representatives,  $\delta \in \operatorname{SL}_2(\mathbb{Z})$ such that $\operatorname{SL}_2(\mathbb{Z}) = \coprod_\delta \Gamma \delta$, then we get $\mathbb{P}^1 (\mathbb{Q}) = \coprod_\delta \Gamma \delta \cdot \{\infty\} = \bigcup_\delta \Gamma \cdot \{\delta \infty\}$. The set $\{\delta\}$ is finite if we assume that $\Gamma \le \operatorname{SL}_2 (\mathbb Z)$ has finite index. But the expression we have now is precisely a set of orbits of $\Gamma$ on $\mathbb{P}^1 (\mathbb Q)$. A subtlety here is that the union on the right is no longer disjoint! For example, $\Gamma_0(p)$ has index $p+1$ in $\operatorname{SL}_2(\mathbb Z)$ so there are $p+1$ representatives $\delta$, but only two of the cusps are inequivalent. Therefore the final step in the computation is to find out for which pairs of $\delta, \delta'$ we have $\Gamma \delta \infty = \Gamma \delta' \infty$.
The idea in your setting is similar, except the role of $\operatorname{SL}_2(\mathbb Z)$ is played by $\Gamma_0(p)$, and your $\Gamma$ is $\Gamma_0(p^2)$. In projective coordinates, the cusps of $\Gamma_0(p)$ are $\infty = [1:0]$ and $0 = [0:1]$, and this is where the equations in the solutions come from.
